# Vertica ILIKE large dataset

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm looking to search through a large table of data for a list of phrases held in another table, but I'm looking to use ILIKE to regex search the text in table a from the phrases in table b. Table b contains over 8,000 phrases, so using a simple OR ILIKE '%' is too complicated. Any ideas of how to use an ILIKE with a SELECT * FROM table2?

Answer (score 0):

You can express the logic as:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.col ilike t2.phrase
             );
```

I imagine this will be quite slow.

Comment: Thanks, giving this a try!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.searcharg ILIKE t2.phrase
;
```

Might be a trifle faster than Gordon's suggestion, but I'm pretty sure not dramatically so ... :-]]

Comment: This join actually fills the inner join memory too much for Vertica to handle in our instance, but thank you!